# How can add datetime to multiples files and rename them using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

How can add datetime to multiples files and rename them using powershell and execute it using Transact-SQL (T-SQL)?

I need execute powershell using xp_cmdshell inside a procedure and this situation:

**Example:**

```
dir c:\dados\*.txt
```

Results:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

and I need rename these files to:

```
a_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.txt 
b_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.txt 
c_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.txt
```

I know how can I rename all files erasing one word, for exemple:
I have:

```
a_20170116_195158.txt
b_20170116_195158.txt
c_20170116_195158.txt
c1_20170116_195158.txt
```

and rename to:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
c1.txt
```

using this command:

```
xp_cmdshell 'powershell "dir p:\files\xmltmp_old | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace ''_20170116_195158'',''''}"'
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing site. It appears there are multiple disciplines you haven't even attempted. Please show us what you have tried and limit your questions to a single question at a time where you get stuck.

Comment: I only put examples to explain the problem. The question is: How can add datetime to multiples files and rename them using powershell and execute it using Transact-SQL (T-SQL)?

Comment: Yes, that's three questions without any visible attempts. 1: How do I rename a file in PS, How do I call SQL from PS, and it appears 3: How do I call my PS script from the command line.

Comment: how I transform this command to execute in tsql: PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\TESTE\DEFAULT> Get-ChildItem c:\dados | rename-item -NewNam
e {$_.name -replace '.txt',((get-date).ToString("_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")+'.txt')}